# Use LINQ to omit some entries in the value part of a dictionary and project this into a new dictonary maintaing original keys

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I have a generic  dictonary which is templated in the following manner:

```
Dictionary<object, IList<ISomeInterface>> dictionary1 = new Dictionary<object,    IList<ISomeInterface>>();
```

If I wanted to omit certain list items against arbitrary keys (that is the items that are in the list contained within the value part of each of the key value pairs making up the dictionary)  given some arbitrary condition (lets say omitting list items where a list item contained the string "abc")

I would expect to able to create/project into a new dictionary which would contain entries which contained lists WITHOUT those items whose name contained "abc"

How do I achieve this using a Lambda expression?

I was trying something like this:

var result1 = dictionary1.Where(x => x.Value == x.Value.Select(y => !y.contains("abc"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To you want it as another dictionary? Try this:

```
var result = original.ToDictionary(
    pair => pair.Key, // Key in result is key in original
    value => pair.Value  // Value in result is query on original value
                 .Where(item => !item.Contains("abc").ToList());
```

EDIT: VB as per the comment:

```
someDictionary.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.key, _ 
            Function(y) y.Value.Where(not y.Value contains("abc").ToList())
```

Comment: Yes, I would like it in another dictionary. I am going to test this very shortly.

Comment: Then why have you posted C# source in your question? Anyway, this should translate reasonably easily to VB - it'll just be a bit uglier due to the more verbose lambda syntax in VB.

Comment: I was POCing in C# but to be fair to myself I did tag it as VB.NET.  I have tried transposing to Vb.net but to no avail....

Comment: Ok, sorted. Not as messy as first thought. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Thus transposed to Vb.net...

someDictionary.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.key, _
                            Function(y) y.Value.Where(not y.Value contains("abc").ToList())

Answer (score 0):

```
var result1 = dictionary1.Select(x => 
     {
          return new KeyValuePair<object, IList<ISomeInterface>>(
                     x.Key, 
                     x.Value.Where(y => y.Contains("abc")).ToList());
     }).ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
```

Comment: Why bother calling Select first and then ToDictionary when you can do it all more simply in one call to ToDictionary?